# Request parameters in Freemarker on Spring 2.5

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I am trying to get request parameters on freemarker page. But I can't figure out how to setup implicit variables like RequestParameters or so.

Here is a thread http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=32846 but I don't where he setup that RequestParameters object.

The only thing I found in docs (more in source code), that it is FreemarkerServlet which can place that variable. But I don't have it in my application. All configurations are done via Spring, i.e. View Resolver.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: No setup should be required.  What happens when you try to access a request parameter?

Comment: As usual: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression Request is undefined on... The same is for RequestParameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For query string `?myparam=abc`, you can get to `myparam` like that:

```
${RequestParameters.myparam}
```

Verified on Spring 3 + Freemarker 2.3.

Don't need any additional configuration for the view handler.

Comment: I suspect this will only work if you're using the FreeMarker servlet. When using Spring (as glaz666 seems to be) @mx answer is the correct one.

Comment: And if you're using spring 4 you can configure using FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that `exposeRequestAttributes` is enabled in your `FreeMarkerViewResolver`, e.g.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
      <property name="cache"  value="true" />
      <property name="prefix" value="" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
      <property name="requestContextAttribute"  value="request" />
      <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
      <property name="exposeRequestAttributes"  value="true" />
      <property name="exposeSessionAttributes"  value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot 1.5 based in anotation into class will be something like:

```
package com.openkm.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

import freemarker.cache.TemplateLoader;
import freemarker.template.TemplateException;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/").setCachePeriod(604800); // One week
    }

    @Bean(name = "freeMarkerViewResolver")
    public FreeMarkerViewResolver getFreeMarkerViewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setExposeSpringMacroHelpers(true);  
        viewResolver.setExposeRequestAttributes(true);
        viewResolver.setExposeSessionAttributes(true);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/ftl/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        viewResolver.setOrder(0);
        viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);
        viewResolver.setRequestContextAttribute("request");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```